# Single Mailbox, with Users having different views instead of their own

Tags: email, email-client

We're looking for an email application, that also doubles as an archive. Where each person would have their own mail, but when permissions allow, they would be able to search the entire archive.

One concept would be something like a single mailbox, with aliases for all the incoming mail, or just a catch-all. Then each mail client / user, would just have a view of that mailbox of the mail they sent or received. Then an administrator could create new views and assign them to users to see other emails.

Comment: It would certainly help to mention the OS it should run on, and the price limit in case of recommendations for paid software – thanks!.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter where it runs, or how much it is. Right now any options are better than none =)

Comment: I have same issue. We use lots of different OSes, but even when searching for any OS at any price I am not finding anything... Except maybe Lotus Notes but IBM is trying to rebrand it and whatnot and deleted its product page.